# What is the user agent DataAccess/1.0

Tags: asp.net, web-services

My ASP.NET website hosts calendars in ical format. These are accessed via a simple service. I log the user agent string (context.Request.UserAgent) to a database.

The vast majority of my calendar requests are from a user agent that identifies as "DataAccess/1.0 (XXXX)" where xxxx is a variable code (eg 8J2, 8C148).

I've searched on http://www.user-agents.org, http://www.useragentstring.com and [Google](http://www.google.com.au/search?hl=en&q=%22user%20agent%22%20%22DataAccess/1.0%22)

What is this user agent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are older iPhone clients of some sort (the XXXX corresponds to the OS release, 8C148 is 4.2.1, 8J2 would be later, probably 4.3.something).